# Javascript: Cant get this custom event listener to work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a zoomIn and zoomOut event listener but I cant seem to make it work. Can someone help me? My code....

```
//Classes for my own personal custom event listeners

var customEvent1 = new CustomEvent(
    'custom1',
    {
        detail: 
        {
            zoomIn: false,
            zoomOut: false,
        },
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
    }
);
document.dispatchEvent(customEvent1);

//Handlers for the custom events 

function custom1Handler(e)
{
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var height, width;
    height = windowHeight;
    width = windowWidth;
    if (height >= windowHeight || width >= windowWidth)
    {
        e.detail.zoomOut = true;
        console.log("Zoomed out");
    }
    else if (width <= windowWidth || width <= windowWidth)
    {
        e.detail.zoomIn = true;
        console.log("Zoomed in");
    }
    else 
    {
        console.log("Cant determine Custom Zoom Event Listener");
    }
}

//Initiate events  

document.addEventListener("custom1", custom1Handler, false);
```

It gives no error, but is not fired off when I zoom in the page or zoom out. What am I doing wrong exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch event after you add listener for it, not before.

```
document.addEventListener("custom1", custom1Handler, false);
document.dispatchEvent(customEvent1);
```

Comment: I still cannot execute it the way I have in mind. Its supposed to fire every single time I zoom in or out. It only does it once.